# How to get DateTime Format String of actual date-time?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'd like to take a datetime string, and get the string version of its format:

e.g. `2017-01-02` would yield `YYYY-MM-dd` for logging purposes if a datetime is parsed incorrectly due to a parsing exception.

Is this possible with `System.DateTime` or any other built-in?

Comment: Why wouldn't 2017-01-02 not yield YYYY-dd-MM?

Comment: And what would you do if you had only a 2 digits year, like this? `01/02/03` Is that January 2nd 2003, or February 1st 2003, or maybe Match 2nd 2001 or February 3rd 2001?

Comment: @rene `2017-01-02` would yield `2017-01-02`. OP needs the following string: `YYYY-MM-dd`.

Comment: A `DateTime` struct doesn't *have* a format. It's the number of 100ns intervals since 01/01/0001 (plus some bit fiddling to derive the `Kind` property). If, on the other hand, you have a *string*, there's no way to tell whether `2017-01-02` is "in" `YYYY-MM-dd` or `YYYY-dd-MM` format.

Comment: @ispiro One of us didn't understand the question. Here is what I got: the OP wants to get a string representing the *format* of the input string - so if the input string is `2017-01-13` the return value should be `yyyy-MM-dd`. but if the input string is `01/02/03` it could represent any of the dates I've listed so it's impossible to know if you want to return `MM/dd/yy`, `dd/MM/yy`, `yy/MM/dd`, `yy/dd/MM` or even `dd/yy/MM`. That's how it's related to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "2017-01-02" would yield "YYYY-MM-dd"

It's not possible. You are asking for *magic*, making *something* out of *nothing*.

There is no way without meta information for a computer (or a human) to decide if that is the 2nd January or the 1st February. Both is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way of getting that format string based on a string that might look like a date.

The closest hack that I can come up with is iterating over all cultures and then trying to ParseExact the predefined DateTime patterns that are found in each culturinfo's DateTimeFormat property.

The hack would look like this:

```
var date = "2017-01-02";

var formats = new Dictionary<string,int>();

// go over all cultures
foreach(var ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
  // each culture has a DateTimeFormatInfo that holds date and time patterns
  foreach(var p in typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo)
                   .GetProperties()
                   .Where(prop => prop.Name.EndsWith("Pattern")))
  { 
    // get a pattern property from the cultureinfo DateTimeFormat
    var fmt = (string) p.GetValue(ci.DateTimeFormat, null);
    try
    {
      // try to parse the date
      DateTime.ParseExact(date,fmt , ci);
      // add the format
      if (formats.Keys.Contains(fmt))
      {
         formats[fmt]++; // how often this was a valid date
      }
      else
      {
         formats.Add(fmt, 1); // first time we found it
      }
    }
    catch
    {
     // no date in this culture for this format, ignore
    }

  }
}

// output the formats that were parsed as a date
foreach(var kv in formats)
{
   // Dump is a linqPad extension, use Console.WriteLine if that bothers you
   kv.Value.Dump(kv.Key);
}
```

and on my box this returns

> **yyyy-MM-dd**
>   40
>   **yyyy-M-d**
>   1

Now for `01/02/2017` it would return:

> **dd/MM/yyyy**
>    255
>
> **d/M/yyyy**
>   93
>
> **M/d/yyyy**
>   20
>
> **d/MM/yyyy**
>   11
>
> **MM/dd/yyyy**
>   2

which shows a bit of the concerns raised in the comments. Without knowing the culture a date string was generated it is a guess what the date format was. Worst case it was a string with numbers and dashes between them.